# ImproperlyConfigured Set the xxxx environment variable - django-environ

Tags: python, django

In my settings.py i'm using django-environ like this:

```
import os
import environ
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

env = environ.Env(
    SECRET_KEY=str,    
)

env_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env')
environ.Env.read_env('.env')

SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

My .env file looks like this

```
SECRET_KEY = ******************
```

However, when I run the app i get

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY
>   environment variable

The .env file is found and lines are being read from it, so there's no problem with finding it, but somehow it doesn't work.

While following the execution thread i discovered that the regex for interpreting the .env lines is returning nothing

#### environ/environ.py

```
        for line in content.splitlines():
        m1 = re.match(r'\A(?:export )?([A-Za-z_0-9]+)=(.*)\Z', line)
        if m1:
            key, val = m1.group(1), m1.group(2)
            m2 = re.match(r"\A'(.*)'\Z", val)
            if m2:
                val = m2.group(1)
            m3 = re.match(r'\A"(.*)"\Z', val)
            if m3:
                val = re.sub(r'\\(.)', r'\1', m3.group(1))
            cls.ENVIRON.setdefault(key, str(val))enter code here
```

re.match(r'\A(?:export )?([A-Za-z_0-9]+)=(.*)\Z', line) is returning none

Am i missing something here?

Comment: env.str(‘SECRET_KEY’)

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan it returns the same exception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer by checking the regex responsible for interpreting the .env lines - \A(?:export )?([A-Za-z_0-9]+)=(.*)\Z

There should be no spaces between the key and the value

Problem:

```
KEY = VALUE
```

Good:

```
KEY=VALUE
```